# Java : What calls could be executed behind the scene to open a UDP socket on port 7500?

Tags: java, udp, sockets

Executing nestat shows the UDP protocol being accessed on port 7500

```
> netstat -naptu | grep 7500
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7500            0.0.0.0:*                           13500/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7500            0.0.0.0:*                           13500/java
```

From what I recall, the JGroups Probe command uses port 7500 by default, but that is about it.

The 13500 process ID is tied to a HUGE Java program. Searching that program and unable to locate any Socket calls or reference to port 7500 within the code. JGroups is used behind the scenes but it is done so via TCP, not UDP.

The lsof command is showing the same PID as the HUGE java program. No idea what is silhouette.

```
> lsof -i :7500
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    13500 tom  191u  IPv4 254027159      0t0  UDP *:silhouette
java    13500 tom  195u  IPv4 254030058      0t0  UDP *:silhouette
```

What calls should I be searching for that would open a UDP socket to pinpoint what is generating the above netstat output and binding it to this HUGE java process?

Comment: Could it be a game? What's the name of the program?

Comment: Check the process with lsof, not the port: `lsof -np 13500`. Also check the process id with `ps xwwwe` and look for command line arguments and environment for clues.

Comment: The lsof -np 13500 returns 470 references.  Lots of jar files and .so files.   There are 2 reference to UDP (UDP *:silhouette) which seems to match the above of still not sure what is the actual call to initiate it.

Comment: According to the port number reservation [table of IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) port 7500 is allocated for silhouette protocol.
According to [Speed guide](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=7500), the port number is also used by "Anarchy Online" game.

Comment: From the information you've provided so far, I would consider JGroups guilty until proven innocent. You know you're using JGroups and JGroups is known to use 7500/UDP as a diagnostics port, so even if you thought you'd only told it to use TCP, I still think it might have opened a listener on 7500/UDP.